# How to send a message in php with paragraphs

Tags: php, message

I'm using the php code below to send a message

```
<?php
$newline = $_GET['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n","$newline");

mail($_GET['to'],$_GET['subject'],$newline,"From: ".$_GET['from']);

header( 'Location: http://my_site.com/POMPC/report.html' ) ;
?>
```

sadly, when I send the message, it appears but everything appears in a straignt line, messing up the message.

Example:

```
Hello,
This is a message. 
Reply.
```

Appears as

> Hello,This is a message. Reply.

Everything is in a straignt line and messes up stuff. How do I mantain the formatting. The message I'm sending is from my desktop application and sends user defined data to me.

Comment: $newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline"); why do you use $newline in quotes? Try it with $newline = str_replace("[N]","\n",$newline); and check if [N] actually occurs in there.

Comment: The `str_replace`s have no effect on the input string from the example. How does your desktop application send the text to php? Try `var_dump($_GET['message']);` to do a little debugging.

Comment: Thanks guys, now everything works. From the first post of 32bitfloat, I've been able to solve it. Thanks to you'all

Answer (score 0):

Use `<p> </p>` tags in the content you get in`$_GET['message']`;

Answer (score 0):

Use `nl2br($_GET['message']);`

Also, why are you using GET method? POST is a better choice

Comment: what is difference between get and post?

Comment: This should clear your doubt http://thinkvitamin.com/code/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your message like this

```
$content=" <h3> Hello </h3>, <p>This is a message. <br/> Long string <br/>";

$content . = " <br/> Thanks <br/> Your Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

Before everything else, make sure that your message contains correct line breaks where you expect them.  You can put this debugging code after the `str_replace` calls:

```
echo "<pre>$newline</pre>";
```

and see whether your text is broken up into lines.  If not, then the issue is in your input.

Next, it looks like your mail reader parses the message as HTML, hence everything is mangled together.  You are not specifying content-type explicitly, therefore it's up to each individual mail reader to decide how to interpret the message.  There are two solutions to your issue:

(1) Declare the message as HTML and use `<br/>` to break up the lines:

```
<?php
$newline = $_GET['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n","$newline");
$newline = nl2br($newline);

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\nFrom: ".$_GET['from'];
mail($_GET['to'],$_GET['subject'],$newline,$headers);

header( 'Location: http://my_site.com/POMPC/report.html' ) ;
?>
```

(2) Declare the message as pure text and leave the line breaks as `\n`:

```
<?php
$newline = $_GET['message'];

$newline = str_replace("[N]","\n","$newline");
$newline = str_replace("[n]","\n","$newline");

$headers = "Content-type: text/html\r\nFrom: ".$_GET['from'];
mail($_GET['to'],$_GET['subject'],$newline,$headers);

header( 'Location: http://my_site.com/POMPC/report.html' ) ;
?>
```

Either of the two should produce the results your want.

Answer (score 0):

### If you want HTML paragraphs:

Using just the `mail()` function you would have to compose the HTML source like this:

Do not write anything in the 3rd parameter `$message`, just leave it blank `''`. And compose rest as such:

```
$additional_headers = <<<MAIL
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=00151747835895c6f804c48dc14b

--00151747835895c6f804c48dc14b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    Pararaph 1
    Pararaph 2

--00151747835895c6f804c48dc14b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

    <p>Pararaph 1</p>
    <p>Pararaph 2</p>

--00151747835895c6f804c48dc14b--
MAIL;

$additional_headers = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $additional_headers);
```

Make sure the text in the **plain/text** area is separated by one or more `\r\n` to get a visual feel similar to the html paragraphs.