# How to send a message in php mail function as line by line

Tags: php, html, email

I need to send a mail message as paragraphs or as line by line,the message if fetched from html form.The message would be like this
"This is first line
 this id second line"
I fetch the value from form as

```
$mesg= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['message']);
$mess= nl2br($mesg);
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message  ='<html><body>';
$message .='<p>Message : '.strip_tags($mess).'</p>';
$message .='</body></html>';
```

but message is shown and send as single line in mail.I have found a similar question but the answers didnt help me much.[the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648615/how-to-send-a-message-in-php-with-paragraphs)

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` <-- why are you using this for email message content?

Comment: Why do you send annoying html email messages if you have just single lines to show? Go with normal, plain text messages, the line breaks will show fine and you don't inflate a simple text to three times its size without any reason. _And_ you won't create security issues for the readers.

Comment: The use of `nl2br()` is correct, but you are stripping it again with `strip_tags()`. You should first use `strip_tags()` and after that use `nl2br()`. --> `nl2br(strip_tags($mess))`.

Comment: @JonStirling  i am storing the same message to database

Comment: @vyshaghs So do that when you're ready to add it to the database not for the e-mail content (or better yet, use prepared statements and get rid of it all together).

Comment: @arkascha its a demo content,actually its a type of complaint form and the datas may be in single lines and paragraphs

Comment: Paragraphs are nothing but text sections separated by an empty line. Certainly nothing that requires html markup.

Comment: @Ivar Thank you,that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use html tag `<br>` because your content-type is `text/html`.

it works without the `content-type` header because then your e-mail will be interpreted an plain text. If you really want to use `\n` you should use content-type: `text/plain` but then you'll lose any markup.